# Extract substring up to specific character non-inclusive

Tags: performance-tuning, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

I was wondering if there is a way with `StringCases` to start at the beginning of a string and stop one character before a known character.

```
s = {{"This is small string 2 !"}, {"There is string 5 ! Or is it 2?"},
     {"This is String n !"}};
```

My problem is that I have a lot of these strings and not all are the same length and some have more characters after the exclamation mark.

I know it involves this code:

```
StringCases[#, Shortest[StartOfString~~___~~ ????????]]& /@ s
```

But I don't know how to finish it (where the `???????` are).

I would like my end result to look like this:

```
final={{"This is small string 2 "},{"There is string 5 "},{"This is String n "}}
```

I have tried searching for this on the forums and have had no luck.

If you could provide an answer or even a direction to go, that would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Also, if this isn't the most efficient way of doing this, or if you have any questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use named [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) to extract a part of matched substring:

```
StringCases[#, str : Shortest[StartOfString ~~ ___] ~~ "!" :> str] & /@ s
```

> ```
> {{{"This is small string 2 "}}, {{"There is string 5 "}}, {{"This is String n "}}}
> ```

or

```
StringCases[#, str : Shortest[StartOfString ~~ ___] ~~ "!" :> str] &@Flatten@ s
```

> ```
> {{"This is small string 2 "}, {"There is string 5 "}, {"This is String n "}}
> ```

---

As [Martin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2305/martin-ender) notes in the comments, another approach is to capture [`Longest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Longest.html) sequence of characters from a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). In this case we don't have to use a named pattern which introduce additional overhead, hence this approach should be more efficient. Since string patterns by default are *greedy*, `Longest` can be omitted in this case:

```
StringCases[#, StartOfString ~~ Except["!"] ...] &
```

Translating `StringExpression`s into equivalent regular expressions sometimes gives substantial increase in performance: this is what *Mathematica* always does under the hood, but not always in the optimal way. Here is verbatim semantic translation:

```
StringCases[#, RegularExpression["^[^!]*"]] &
```

(read [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#337819047) on how to find out what a regex *Mathematica* generates from a `StringExpression`).

And another regex without capturing group *and* without use of a negated character class:

```
StringCases[#, RegularExpression["^.*?(?=!)"]] &
```

Note that this last regex can't be expressed as a combination of usual Wolfram Language patterns because it uses a [*positive lookahead* zero-length assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which has no equivalent in the world of Wolfram Language symbolic pattern objects.

---

### Performance comparison

Here is a timing comparison of the all suggested solutions (on a very large number of short strings):

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
s1 = ConstantArray["There is string 5 ! Or is it 2?", 2*10^5];

{First@AbsoluteTiming[# /@ s1], #} & /@ {
    StringCases[#, str : Shortest[StartOfString ~~ ___] ~~ "!" :> str] &,
    StringCases[#, RegularExpression["^(.*?)!"] -> "$1"] &,
    StringCases[#, StartOfString ~~ Except["!"] ...] &,
    StringCases[#, RegularExpression["^[^!]*"]] &,
    StringCases[#, RegularExpression["^.*?(?=!)"]] &,
    StringDelete[#, "!" ~~ ___] &, StringExtract[#, "!" -> 1] &,
    StringTake[#, StringPosition[#, "!", 1][[1, 1]] - 1] &,
    StringDrop[#, {StringPosition[#, "!", 1][[1, 1]], -1}] &} // 
  Grid[#, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thin, LightGray]] &

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> [image: grid]
>
> ```
> 102886352
> ```

Another comparison suggested by [Martin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2305/martin-ender) (on a string where it takes a while to find the `"!"`):

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
s2 = StringRepeat["There is string 5 ", 10^5] <> "! Or is it 2?";
results = {};

{(AppendTo[results, #2]; #1) & @@ AbsoluteTiming[#@s2], #} & /@ {
    StringCases[#, str : Shortest[StartOfString ~~ ___] ~~ "!" :> str][[1]] &,
    StringCases[#, RegularExpression["^(.*?)!"] -> "$1"][[1]] &,
    StringCases[#, StartOfString ~~ Except["!"] ...][[1]] &,
    StringCases[#, RegularExpression["^[^!]*"]][[1]] &,
    StringCases[#, RegularExpression["^.*?(?=!)"]][[1]] &,
    StringDelete[#, "!" ~~ ___] &,
    StringExtract[#, "!" -> 1] &,
    StringTake[#, StringPosition[#, "!", 1][[1, 1]] - 1] &,
    StringDrop[#, {StringPosition[#, "!", 1][[1, 1]], -1}] &} // 
  Grid[#, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thin, LightGray]] &

SameQ @@ results

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> [image: grid]
>
> ```
> True
>
> 82707472
> ```

The conclusion: [Martin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2305/martin-ender)'s solution via negated character class *with* greedy quantifier outperforms others in general: `RegularExpression["^[^!]*"]`. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140752/280) dedicated Q&A about why the equivalent string expression `StartOfString ~~ Except["!"] ...` is two orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: Alternatively: `StringCases[#, StartOfString ~~ Except["!"] ...] &`

Comment: The very last regex seems like a bad idea. I'm pretty sure that the negative character class *and* the greedy quantifier would be more efficient, and ungreedy quantifiers should be avoided whenever possible, because they can often lead to unwanted matches in more complicated patterns.

Comment: @MartinEnder I added the regex based on *positive lookahead* mainly for educational purposes, but as you can see from the timing comparison it is almost as efficient as your suggestion. I also do not agree with your statement that "ungreedy quantifiers should be avoided whenever possible". They do what they are intended to do and work quite reliably if you use them in the right way.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Try a string where it takes a while to find the `!`, e.g. `StringRepeat["There is string 5 ", 100] <> "! Or is it 2?"`.  The negative character class and greedy quantifier are *much* faster. The problem with the other solution in terms of efficiency is that ungreedy quantifiers require a lot of backtracking. It tries one character, then fails at the lookahead, then it tries two characters and fails at the lookahead, etc etc. The greedy solution just keeps going as long as possible and never has to backtrack.

Comment: As for using ungreedy quantifiers in general, I'm happy to continue the discussion in chat, but my main problem is that they're poorly understood and often result in less robust code (even though that's not the case here).

Comment: @MartinEnder I added new timing comparison, and it proves you are right about efficiency of greedy quantifiers *when it takes a while to find the `"!"`*.   Surprisingly, `StringExtract` beats regex in this case.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yeah true, but I'm also surprised how insanely slow the pattern-matching equivalent of the fast regex becomes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55762/discussion-between-alexey-popkov-and-martin-ender).

Answer (score 3):

```
StringDelete[#, "!"~~___]& /@ s
StringExtract[#, "!"->1]& /@ s
StringTake[#, StringPosition[## & @@ #, "!", 1][[1, 1]] - 1] & /@ s
StringDrop[#, {StringPosition[## & @@ #, "!", 1][[1, 1]], -1}] & /@ s
```

all give

> `{{"This is small string 2 "}, {"There is string 5 "}, {"This is String n "}}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex variant:

```
{{"This is small string 2 !"}, {"There is string 5 ! Or is it 2?"},
 {"This is String n !"}} /. s_String :>
      First[StringCases[s, RegularExpression["^(.*?)!"] -> "$1"]]
```

> ```
> {{"This is small string 2 "}, {"There is string 5 "}, {"This is String n "}}
> ```

Comment: Since the OP wants "to start at the beginning of a string and stop one character before a known character", the *greedy* quantifier `+` isn't the correct choice in the general case. The *lazy* version `+?` is more appropriate.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point; thanks @Alexey.

Comment: The condition "to start at the beginning of a string" is forgotten too (it is  the caret  `^` ).

Comment: Ah, this is what I get when trying to answer without checking with the references. Thank you!

Comment: A better alternative to ungreedy quantifiers is to use a greedy negative characters class, `^[^!]*`. (Your regex will also fail if `!` is the first character.)

Comment: @J.M. I corrected your answer according to Martin's remark. Also I removed redundant capturing group `(.*)`.

Comment: @Alexey, thanks; I got too busy to address Martin's comment promptly.

Comment: @Martin, testing confirms it; thank you!