# Dispatch is not working in StringReplace

Tags: performance-tuning, string-manipulation

I tried to improove a function I wrote to modify "castellano" the proper name for spanish to coherent (so that there's no exception rules to phonetics). I made this with `StringReplace` with a long list of rules.

```
euzk[cad_] := 
 StringReplace[
  cad, {"á" -> "a", "é" -> "e", "í" -> "i", "ó" -> "o", "ú" -> "u", 
   "ca" -> "ka", "ce" -> "ze", "ci" -> "zi", "co" -> "ko", 
   "cu" -> "ku", "ch" -> "c", "cl" -> "kl", "cr" -> "kr", 
   "cc" -> "kz", "cg" -> "kg", "cn" -> "kn", "cp" -> "kp", 
   "ct" -> "kt", "ge" -> "je", "gi" -> "ji", "gue" -> "ge", 
   "gui" -> "gi", "h" -> "", "qu" -> "k", "v" -> "b", "w" -> "u", 
   "y" -> "i"}]
```

As I read about `Dispatch` and how can make functions run faster I made

```
eusk = {"á" -> "a", "é" -> "e", "í" -> "i", "ó" -> "o", "ú" -> "u", 
   "ca" -> "ka", "ce" -> "ze", "ci" -> "zi", "co" -> "ko", 
   "cu" -> "ku", "ch" -> "c", "cl" -> "kl", "cr" -> "kr", 
   "cc" -> "kz", "cg" -> "kg", "cn" -> "kn", "cp" -> "kp", 
   "ct" -> "kt", "ge" -> "je", "gi" -> "ji", "gue" -> "ge", 
   "gui" -> "gi", "h" -> "", "qu" -> "k", "v" -> "b", "w" -> "u", 
   "y" -> "i"};
```

then

```
deusk = Dispatch[eusk]
```

and finally

```
euzk[cad_] := StringReplace[cad, deusk]
```

But when try to use it... receive

```
StringReplace::srep: Dispatch[Length: 27] is not a valid string replacement rule.
```

I can of course leave the function as list of rules, but `Dispatch` looks like so efficient. Can I use it otherwise? Some advice ?

Comment: I believe `StringReplace` compiles to `RegularExpression` generally, making `Dispatch` is unnecessary.

Comment: @-b3m2a1 so I must consider that this faster capacity is already got otherwise ?

Comment: @AnxonPués Yes, exactly. But writing your rules directly in terms of `RegularExpression` [sometimes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140752/280) can give you a performance gain (and [sometimes opposite](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25677/280)).

Answer (score 5):

`Dispatch` is designed to optimize lists of replacement rules for the purposes of such functions as `Replace`, `ReplaceAll`, `ReplaceRepeated` and `ReplaceList`, it is not intended to be used with [string patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html) (`StringReplace`, `StringReplaceList`, `StringCases`). *Mathematica* translates string patterns to regular expressions which will be further compiled by the PCRE library and cached (see more info [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#337819047) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#319138910)), what already gives huge speed-up.

In your particular case you should just use your replacement rules "as is" for achieving the best possible performance:

```
euzk[cad_] := StringReplace[cad, eusk]
```

In some other cases when you need to replace not a literal substring, but a string pattern, rewriting your string pattern (or a part of the pattern) in terms of `RegularExpression` [can give a performance gain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140752/280), but [not always](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25677/280).