# Patterns with AND, OR, NOT

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I pretend to use `DictionaryLookup[{"Language", complex_Pattern}]` but can not achieve it finally to get it with like three layers ... Specially, I tried `Except[c, p] ...` but did not arrive to use it because did not produce de wished output

```
css_ss _s = 
 Select[Select[DictionaryLookup[{"Catalan", ___ ~~ "s" ~~ ___ }], 
   StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "ss" ~~ ___] == False &], 
  StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "s"] == False &]
```

But the output is what I pretended, the question is: Is there a less layered way to arrive at the same point?

Comment: Maybe try `Cases[...,Except[...]]` instead of using `Select`.

Comment: I forgot to say I had tested Cases too, the problem is that using Except I am affraid I do not know how to use and the help does not make it clear, Tried Except[c,___~~"ss"~~___] and also ___~~Except["ss"]~~___   well like I told before I do not have strong knowledge on Patterns and Except  and about Cases and Select I must recognize that I feel more confortable with Select... finally it worked in this onion-style way

Comment: Mathematica doesn't recognise the syntax `css_ss _s =`.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: `StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "s"] == False &` is equivalent to setting pattern in `DictionaryLookup` to `___~~"s"~~___~~Except["s"]`

Comment: @mikado - well this naming was not clever I detected the problem after and now use without underlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few different approaches.

```
dict = DictionaryLookup[{"Catalan", ___ ~~ "s" ~~ ___}, 140];

DeleteCases[dict, str_ /; StringMatchQ[str,
   Alternatives[___ ~~ "ss" ~~ ___  ,  ___ ~~ "s"]]]

Select[dict, Not@StringMatchQ[#,
    Alternatives[___ ~~ "ss" ~~ ___  ,  ___ ~~ "s"]] &]

Select[dict, (StringFreeQ[#, "ss"] && StringFreeQ[#, "s" ~~ EndOfString]) &]

(*  {"abalisa", "abalisà", "abalisada", "abalisam", "abalisant", "abalisar"}   *)
```

I could not get `Except` to work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
nots = RegularExpression["[^s]"];
DictionaryLookup[{"Catalan", a___ ~~ "s" ~~ b__ /; StringEndsQ[a, nots] && StringStartsQ[b, nots] && StringEndsQ[b, nots]}]
```

where the substring `a` has a string length of $ \geq 0 $ and not ends with `"s"`, and at the same time the substring `b` has a length of $ \geq 1 $ without `"s"` as its two ends.

And it seems that `RegularExpression["[^s]"]` can be replaced by `Except["s"]`.

Comment: FYI: [Why `Except` is so slow as compared to equivalent `RegularExpression`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140752/280)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for the information.