# StringCases with string replace and with escape characters

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

I want to extract url address of all css files inside HTML source.
First output is as expected. But why second and third outputs are different? Notice that only "href" was removed from beginning of the first searching string and then "href=", but `Shortest[x__]` should remain same, so I would expect all outputs to be the same.
What I am doing wrong?

```
str="\"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/some/path/to/css/name.min.css";
StringCases[str,"href=\""~~Shortest[x__]~~y:".css"->x~~y]
StringCases[str,"=\""~~Shortest[x__]~~y:".css"->x~~y]
StringCases[str,"\""~~Shortest[x__]~~y:".css"->x~~y]
Clear[str]

(* {"/some/path/to/css/name.min.css"} *)
(* {"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/some/path/to/css/name.min.css"} *)
(* {"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/some/path/to/css/name.min.css"} *)
```

**Update:**

First I thought it has something to do with escape characters used inside strings but here is a simple example:

```
StringCases["A---A--A____B-A_B-A---A______B---AAAAB","A"~~Shortest[x__]~~"B"->x]

(* {"---A--A____","_","---A______","AAA"} *)
```

But I believe correct result should be:

```
(* {"____","_","______"} *)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just a consequence of [how the *lazy* quantifier in regular expression works](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72293/280). Online [test](https://regex101.com/r/O2Neox/1) gives the same result.

You should understand that string expressions are first converted to regular expressions by *Mathematica*. You can see the result with [`` StringPattern`PatternConvert ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#337819047):

```
StringPattern`PatternConvert[#][[1]] & /@ {"href=\"" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ y : ".css", 
  "=\"" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ y : ".css", "\"" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ y : ".css"}
```

> ```
> {"(?ms)href=\"(.+?)(\\.css)", "(?ms)=\"(.+?)(\\.css)", "(?ms)\"(.+?)(\\.css)"}
> ```

Hence you shouln't be fooled by the name `Shortest`: it has no relation to *Mathematica*'s own patter matcher's `Shortest`, which behaves differently.

Further reading:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72293/280
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108399/280
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121855/280
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139878/280

---

**UPDATE**

On [this](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazytrap) page, several techniques to overcome this feature of the *lazy* quantifier are provided, including the most general (but not the most efficient) [Tempered Greedy Token Solution](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed). It can be applied as follows <del>for making an equivalent of what could be called a *true* shortest `BlankNullSequence` string expression</del>*****:

```
Clear[shortest]
shortest[start_, end_, "IncludeBoundaries" -> True] := 
  RegularExpression[
   StringTemplate["`START`(?:(?!`START`)(?!`END`).)*`END`"][<|"START" -> start, 
     "END" -> end|>]];
shortest[start_, end_] := shortest[start, end, "IncludeBoundaries" -> True]
shortest[start_, end_, "IncludeBoundaries" -> False] := 
  RegularExpression[
   StringTemplate["(?<=`START`)(?:(?!`START`)(?!`END`).)*(?=`END`)"][<|"START" -> start, 
     "END" -> end|>]];
```

Testing:

```
front = "A";
back = "B";
str = "A---A--A____B-A_B-A---A______B---AAAAB";
StringCases[str, shortest[front, back, "IncludeBoundaries" -> False]]
```

> ```
> {"____", "_", "______", ""}
> ```

```
front = "href=\"";
back = "\\.css";
str = "\"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" \
href=\"/some/path/to/css/name.min.css";
StringCases[str, shortest[front, back, "IncludeBoundaries" -> False]]
front = "=\"";
StringCases[str, shortest[front, back, "IncludeBoundaries" -> False]]
front = "\"";
StringCases[str, shortest[front, back, "IncludeBoundaries" -> False]]
```

> ```
> {"/some/path/to/css/name.min"}
> ```

> ```
> {"/some/path/to/css/name.min"}
> ```

> ```
> {"/some/path/to/css/name.min"}
> ```

*****As the OP shows in the [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272615/stringcases-with-string-replace-and-with-escape-characters/272621#comment680945_272621), this method fails miserably in more complicated cases:

```
front = "tomato";
back = "iconic";
str = "gffghtomatomato12345iconiconictomatomatoiconiconic";
StringCases[str, shortest[front, back, "IncludeBoundaries" -> False]]
```

> ```
> {"mato12345", "mato", ""}
> ```

This result is **wrong**. The expected result is `{"12345",""}`.

Here is another version which gives the desired result:

```
Clear[shortest2]
shortest2[str_, start_, end_] := 
  StringCases[str, 
   RegularExpression[
     StringTemplate["(?!.{1,`len`}`START`)`START`((?:(?!`START`)(?!`END`).)*)`END`"][<|
       "len" -> StringLength[start], "START" -> start, "END" -> end|>]] -> "$1"];

front = "tomato";
back = "iconic";
str = "gffghtomatomato12345iconiconictomatomatoiconiconic";
shortest2[str, front, back]
```

> ```
> {"12345", ""}
> ```

However, in some special cases this method also fails:

```
front = "NotEnd";
back = "End";
str = "NotEndNotEnd1234NotEnd";
shortest2[str, front, back]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Hence the approach [suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272667/280) by the OP should be preferred.

---

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that I managed to find a really universal solution through regular expressions:

```
Clear[ShortestStringBetween]
Options[ShortestStringBetween] = {"IncludeBoundaries" -> False, 
   "BoundaryOverlaps" -> False};
ShortestStringBetween[str_String, start_String, end_String, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{bInclude = OptionValue["IncludeBoundaries"],
    bOvelap = OptionValue["BoundaryOverlaps"]},
   Which[
    bInclude && Not[bOvelap],
    StringCases[str, RegularExpression[
      StringTemplate["`START`(?:(?!`END`).(?<!`START`))*`END`"][
       <|"START" -> start, "END" -> end|>]]],
    Not[bInclude] && Not[bOvelap],
    StringCases[str, RegularExpression[
       StringTemplate["`START`((?:(?!`END`).(?<!`START`))*)`END`"][
        <|"START" -> start, "END" -> end|>]] -> "$1"],
    Not[bInclude] && bOvelap,
    StringCases[str, RegularExpression[
      StringTemplate["(?<=`START`)(?:(?!`END`).(?<!`START`))*(?=`END`)"][
       <|"START" -> start, "END" -> end|>]]],
    bInclude && bOvelap,
    StringCases[str, match : RegularExpression[
        StringTemplate["(?<=`START`)(?:(?!`END`).(?<!`START`))*(?=`END`)"][
         <|"START" -> start, "END" -> end|>]] :> StringJoin[start, match, end]]
    ]];
```

Note that the `start` and `end` parameters are directly inserted into `RegularExpression` and therefore must be regular expressions in the *Mathematica* format. And since PCRE (on which `RegularExpression` is based) doesn't support infinite repetition within a [lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind), the `start` parameter [must be](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width) a fixed-length regexp or contain alternations of different but pre-determined lengths (for example, `"cat|raccoon"`). The `end` parameter has no such restriction. But I haven't tested how this implementation behaves with non-fixed length parameters.

It works correctly in the all test cases:

```
front = "tomato";
back = "iconic";
str = "gffghtomatomato12345iconiconictomatomatoiconiconic";
ShortestStringBetween[str, front, back]
```

> ```
> {"12345", ""}
> ```

```
front = "NotEnd";
back = "End";
str = "NotEndNotEnd1234NotEnd";
ShortestStringBetween[str, front, back]
ShortestStringBetween[str, front, back, "BoundaryOverlaps" -> True]
```

> ```
> {"Not"}
> ```

> ```
> {"Not", "1234Not"}
> ```

Comment: So simply it is a bug anyway. I do not think it worked the same way in older versions.

Comment: @azerbajdzan It isn't a bug, and it works the same way in version 8.0.4 (I just tested).

Comment: How it is not a bug? What is the purpose of `Shortest` when it does not represent the shortest possible string then?

Comment: @azerbajdzan It represents the *lazy* quantifier from regular expressions in the Wolfram Language. I agree that the decision to call it `Shortest` is dubious. Please read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108399/280) answer for a discussion.

Comment: I tried to read, but I can not follow.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I updated the answer with a `RegularExpression`-based solution.

Comment: I like my version more, it is less complicated and gives the shortest string without overlaps in all circumstances. My code and your code are not equivalent. My version returns: `shortest["gffghtomatomato12345iconiconictomatomatoiconiconic","tomato","iconic"]=={"12345",""}` while yours `StringCases["gffghtomatomato12345iconiconictomatomatoiconiconic", shortest["tomato", "iconic", "IncludeBoundaries" -> False]]=={"mato12345","mato",""}`. Your code did not even find "12345" and on the other hand returns `"mato"` which is longer then `""`. `"mato"` would be valid only if overlaps are allowed.

Comment: ...but if overlaps were allowed then beside `"mato"` there would be missing `"icon"` in your output. Furthermore - if overlaps were allowed then "shortest" loses its meaning because then all occurrences of `start~~___~~end` would be valid.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I see. Thank you for a good example.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I updated the answer with another version which gives correct result in such cases.

Comment: @azerbajdzan It seems that I still managed to find a really universal solution through regular expressions. Please see the "UPDATE 2" section.

Comment: Great. Now I know why they choose to use the most simplest way of definition of `Shortest`. Because it is hard to test the "real shortest" in all circumstances of different possible nested strings. You can never be sure whether you overlooked some complexly nested string for which it might not work.

Answer (score 1):

This finds shortest strings inside `str` that are between strings `front` and `back` (including empty string).

```
shortest[str_,front_,back_]:=Module[{p1,p2,p},
p1={#,1}&/@StringPosition[str,front][[All,2]];
p2={#,2}&/@StringPosition[str,back][[All,1]];
p={1,-1}+#&/@SequenceCases[Sort[Join[p1,p2]],{{_,1},{_,2}}][[All,All,1]];
StringTake[str,p]
]
```

```
front="A";
back="B";
str="A---A--A____B-A_B-A---A______B---AAAAB";
shortest[str,front,back]
Clear[front,back,str]

(* {"____", "_", "______", ""} *)
```

```
front="href=\"";
back=".css";
str="\"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/some/path/to/css/name.min.css";
shortest[str,front,back]
front="=\"";
shortest[str,front,back]
front="\"";
shortest[str,front,back]
Clear[front,back,str]

(* {"/some/path/to/css/name.min"} *)
(* {"/some/path/to/css/name.min"} *)
(* {"/some/path/to/css/name.min"} *)
```